# How to put a image and text inside a button and make it center?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
#submitCancel {
  float:left;
  width:49%;
  height:6em;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  /*font-size: 2em;*/
  border-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

#submitCancel img {
  border:1px black solid;
}

.btnText {
  font-size: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="submitCancel" onclick="closeForm();">
  <img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/android-icons/hyaline-icons-by-qishui/png/88x88/camera.png">
  <span class="btnText">Cancel</span>
</button>
```

I try to  put a image and text inside a button and make it center.
How can I do it? I

Answer (score 2):

This should work. Using align="middle" in the img tag.

```
  <img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/android-icons/hyaline-icons-by-qishui/png/88x88/camera.png" align="middle">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```css
#submitCancel {
  float:left;
  width:49%;
  height:6em;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  /*font-size: 2em;*/
  border-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

#submitCancel img {
  border:1px black solid;
}

.btnText {
  font-size: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="submitCancel" onclick="closeForm();">
<img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/android-icons/hyaline-icons-by-qishui/png/88x88/camera.png" align="middle">      
<span class="btnText">Cancel</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways.

Add a `vertical-align: middle;` property to the following class.

```
#submitCancel img {
    border: 1px black solid;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**or**

add a `align="center"` attribute to the image tag.

```
<img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/android-icons/hyaline-icons-by-qishui/png/88x88/camera.png" align="center">
```